# 10K rep users should have the Cornify button back

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, 10k-tools

For those not familiar with Cornify: [StackOverflow April Fools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/704353/the-fancy-and-amazing-april-fools-question)

I personally believe that the option to completely cornify our screen is a God/Allah/Buddha/FSM/Sarah Palin given right and that achieving 10K rep should be seen as a milestone worthy of some actual celebration.

I mean, really...all we get is the ability to see spam and offensive flags? We get the ability to vote to delete and undelete? **LAME**. There is no real reward in any of that. The only reward you get is the self high-five or the congratulatory self back-pat, and for those of us with low self esteem, that just isn't enough. We need the sparkles and the magical beauty of unicorns to say "YOU DID IT! CONGRATS!"

This isn't going to bother non-pony lovers (those infidels!) since the cornification will only show up on your own screen.

Join me brothers and sisters (even though we know there are no females on the internet) and let's bring back the Cornify!

Comment: Greasemonkey anyone?

Comment: Oh great. TheTXI is smoking the crack again.

Comment: +1 I concur, with at least 15 characters.

Comment: It's not even Friday.

Comment: Brad Gilbert: You're assuming I'm not deathly serious.

Comment: @TheTXI: How do you light the crack pipe with those tiny pony hooves?

Comment: Bill: Leprechauns.

Comment: May his noodly appendage touch this question. rAmen!

Comment: Giant and amazing unicorns and rainbows FTW!

Comment: @RichB Was that sarcasm? I don't see why it wouldn't be a cause for actual celebration! Wheeeeee!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

GreaseMonkey script:

```
(function() {
    function GM_wait() {
        if (typeof unsafeWindow.jQuery == 'undefined') { 
            window.setTimeout(GM_wait,100); 
        } else { 
            $ = unsafeWindow.jQuery; letsJQuery(); 
        }
    }
    GM_wait();
    function letsJQuery() {
        if ($("#hlinks span.reputation-score").text().length > 5 || $("#hlinks span.mod-flair").text() == "♦")
        {
                $("head").append("<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.cornify.com/js/cornify.js'></script>");
                $("<a href='http://www.cornify.com' ></a>")
                    .append("<img src='http://www.cornify.com/assets/cornify.gif' style='vertical-align:top' alt='Cornify' />")
                    .appendTo(".post-menu")
                    .click(function() {
                        $(this).closest("table").find("td:gt(0) img").attr("src", function() { return this.src.replace(/www\.gravatar\.com/, "unicornify.appspot.com"); });
                        cornify_add();
                        return false;
                    })
                    .before("<span class='lsep'>|</span>");
        }
    }
})();
```

**Edit**: Now should only function if you have greater than 10k rep as per requirements. :)

**Edit 2**: Didn't realise the format of the rep at the top of the page was 12,345 rather than 12.3k. Should work now.

**Edit 3**: I've added [balpha's spectacular unicorn gravatars](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37328/my-godits-full-of-unicorns) to the script, since I think they fit nicely (each cornify link only unicornifies the gravatars for that post/question).

Also fixed for people with over 100k rep (since I'm positive that [Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) & [Marc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) both cried themselves to sleep at night once they hit 100k & their cornify button stopped working).

Note that I can't actually test either of the changes properly, since my work is blocking appspot & I don't have 100k+ rep... so if anyone sees any problems let me know (or just edit the script directly).

Comment: Nice. One thing though - you can't test for the index of "k" because the rep at the top of the page (which is what I assume you're attempting to access) isn't abbreviated with "k". Instead I suggest looking at the number of characters from the start to the comma - if it's 2 (or more, as it may be the case soon) show the cornify button.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure how it was formatted & guessed it was the same as elsewhere. Just showing my sub-10k naivety... updated to check for the index of the comma, as you suggest. So it should work until someone hits 1,000,000. :P

Comment: One last request :-) Can you check for the existence of ♦ as well? If so, always display the button. Thanks! This is what it looks like: `<a href="/users/658/kyle-cronin" >Kyle Cronin</a><span class="mod-flair" title="moderator">&#9830;</span>&nbsp;<span class="reputation-score" title="reputation score">6,844</span>`

Comment: I wasn't sure how it would interpret those crazy encoded chars, and had no way to check. Glad you got it on your own :)

Comment: Nice one. Pity I can't even use my own script... unless someone wants to go upvote all my answers on SO each day for the next month or so. You know, for testing purposes. ;)

Comment: You will have to change that for the new top bar.

Answer (score 9):

While it's great to be able to Cornify your *own* copy, I think the real joy comes in sharing the Cornification with others. That's why I propose introducing a "vote to Cornify" ([proposed earlier here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11673/what-do-you-dislike-with-stackoverflow/11704#11704)) whereby 10k (or some similar, high rep) users can vote to Cornify or Uncornify the page.

Comment: I guarantee that would result in permanent Cornification.

Comment: I would use all my flags every day.

Comment: I think that Closed Votes should have a checkmark on the bottom to cornify.

Answer (score 1):

StackOverflow needs to add an itemshop where people can buy stuff like cornify for TrilogyPoints. They are almost like Reputation points except that they cost money and are only for buying stuff like that.

I heard that the next feature will be that you can replace the top ad bar (which is hidden for 200+ rep) with a FarmVille game.

Needless to say, the talks with Evony are ongoing, but Evony wants to wait until the counter on the StackOverflow ad inquiry page reaches 10 million so that they are even partners.