# Something exciting should happen when you reach 10K reputation

Tags: feature-request

I just reached 10,000 reputation on Stack Overflow and was disappointed that nothing glamorous or exciting happened that thrilled me.

I don't care what it is, but there should be a happy surprise when we hit 10k.

Maybe we could have unicorns dancing over our usernames.

Comment: When I hit 10K the timing was perfect that, on the same day, I accepted a job found through SO Careers.  That was pretty exciting :)

Comment: So you didn't notice when we did that thing? I mean, we all did our best. And you didn't even pay attention! Well, we're certainly not doing that again. In fact, I won't even tell you what it was that we did.

Comment: You want one time party or some permanent ubber cool effect?

Comment: As soon as I got 10k I followed all those links to fun deleted questions I'd found when I had a lower rep. e.g. Here: [Popular Deleted Questions list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73455)

Comment: Yeah. It's... anti-climatic.

Comment: You get the bright orange nag-badge saying "n flags are waiting to be reviewed by you" next to your user name in the title bar. Close enough to dancing unicorns for me.

Comment: So tempted to close as a dupe of [10K rep users should have the Cornify button back](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13592/10k-rep-users-should-have-the-cornify-button-back)....

Comment: Hmm.. what about free hand circle automagically drawn around your username for whole day? :D

Comment: It does, you get access to [the moderator tools](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/moderator-tools).

Answer (score 7):

Something does, the number of digits in your reputation jumps from four to five.

But in all seriousness, you do have other menu options that are made available to you when you hit 10K (the 10K tools), and it's appearance is not insignificant.

I think the best thing that could be done without annoying users is what happens already; the orange notification banner pops up at the top indicating you've hit that rep level and that the tools are now available to you.

Anything beyond that, IMO is pretty campy, and while SO gets away with a certain amount of it, the reason they do so is because they *do so little of it*.  Flooding my screen with unicorns isn't going to make me want to do more.

I think this is one of those cases where less is more.

Comment: It already does the orange notification thing.

Comment: @PeterOlson Updated.  It's been a *long* time since I hit 10K

Comment: Not here, casper! ;)

Comment: @casper yeah, wonder if you get 10K tools when you already have mod tools?

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd Good point, we'll have to find out when I get there.  Or I could go for 10K on *some other* SE site, but it could be argued I do enough for SE already =P

Comment: @Adam-with-loose-morals-(-and-a-degenerate-) I'm not sure how you reconcile the two, but whatever helps you get through the day.

Comment: @casper - I reconcile the two by drinking until the empty feeling in my soul goes away...

Comment: @AdamRackis Damn, that's sad.  I *almost* shed a tear.

Comment: @casper - meh - the drinking *and also* my sock puppet friends help keep me happy.  Mostly the sock puppets.

Answer (score 1):

You get notification about edits, flags that are posted, in **totally different backgrounds**.

What else do you want?

> <sub>BTW, I threw a little treat to my buddies at 10K+ :)</sub>

Comment: Where is that quote from?

Comment: @Joachim I am not sure. May be I was using it as a formatting style than as an actual quote from someone else.